# Convert integer to hex-string with specific format

Tags: python, string, int, hex

I am new to python and have following problem: I need to convert an integer to a hex string with 6 bytes.

e.g.
281473900746245 --> "\xFF\xFF\xBF\xDE\x16\x05"

The format of the hex-string is important. The length of the int value is variable.

The format '0xffffbf949309L' don't work for me. (I get this with hex(int-value))

---

My **final solution** (after some "playing") is:

```
def _tohex(self, int_value):
    data_ = format(int_value, 'x')

    result = data_.rjust(12, '0')
    hexed = unhexlify(result)

    return hexed
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Do you want the string of length 6 defined by the Python string literal `"\xFF\xFF\xBF\xDE\x16\x05"` or the string of length 24 given by `"\\xFF\\xFF\\xBF\\xDE\\x16\\x05"`?

Comment: The terms "hex string" and "format" are misleading, what you really want is to form an integer of arbitrary size to a byte string with big-endian order.

Comment: Please excuse my English - I just translated the terms from my first language - thank you for the translation.

Answer (score 13):

There might be a better solution, but you can do this:

```
x = 281473900746245
decoded_x = hex(x)[2:].decode('hex') # value: '\xff\xff\xbf\xde\x16\x05'
```

Breakdown:

```
hex(x)                     # value: '0xffffbfde1605'
hex(x)[2:]                 # value: 'ffffbfde1605'
hex(x)[2:].decode('hex')   # value: '\xff\xff\xbf\xde\x16\x05'
```

**Update:**

Per @multipleinstances and @Sven's comments, since you might be dealing with long values, you might have to tweak the output of hex a little bit:

```
format(x, 'x')     # value: 'ffffbfde1605'
```

Sometimes, however, the output of hex might be an odd-length, which would break decode, so it'd probably be better to create a function to do this:

```
def convert(int_value):
   encoded = format(int_value, 'x')

   length = len(encoded)
   encoded = encoded.zfill(length+length%2)

   return encoded.decode('hex')
```

Comment: On my system, `hex(x)[2:]` produces `ffffbfde1605L`, which causes a `TypeError` in decode. `hex(x)[2:-1]` might be better.

Comment: @multipleinterfaces: unconditionally stripping the last byte is a bad idea.  `hex(x)[2:].rstrip("L")` should do the job, though.

Comment: @multiple Actually, this won't work for L values since the hex output can be an odd length (for some reason).

Comment: @Manny: Your solution does not work for any number that consists of an odd number of hex characters.  For example, `2748` is `0xABC`, and `str.decode('hex')` would require `0abc` instead of `abc`.

Comment: To save yourself from the hassle with `0x` prefix and `L` suffix, use `format(number, 'x')` instead of `hex()`.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.2 or above, you can use the [`to_bytes()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method of the interger.

```
>>> i = 281473900746245       
>>> i.to_bytes((i.bit_length() + 7) // 8, "big")
b'\xff\xff\xbf\xde\x16\x05'
```

Comment: Worth to mention that you will need to precompute the desired length (using `math.log` or `int.bit_length`) and probably want to specify `byteorder='big'`.

Comment: @Ferdinand: Thanks, expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use Python 3.2 (I'm pretty sure you don't), consider the next approach:

```
>>> i = 281473900746245
>>> hex_repr = []
>>> while i:
...     hex_repr.append(struct.pack('B', i & 255))
...     i >>= 8
...
>>> ''.join(reversed(hex_repr))
'\xff\xff\xbf\xde\x16\x05'
```

Comment: I tested this approach... it only works if the int-value isn't to short. e.g. with i=2 I get '\x02\x1d\x08\xff\xff\xbf\xde\x16\x05'...